# Python selenium iterate through Class Name

Tags: python, selenium, classname

I am trying to iterate through all items which have the class name `status ready`, and then do something at each iteration.

My problem is that, even if I wait a long time to search for that class name, it is not found:

```
wait(driver, 600).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "status ready")))
```

Here is the the top part of the inspection from chrome
http://pastebin.com/4aMyb8yV

(the important part is class='status ready')
The website is scrolls infinitely, but I would like to iterate through elements, even if I don't see them at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use compound classes with search `By.CLASS_NAME`, use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` instead:

```
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".status.ready")))
```

Comment: Ok great, could you help me figure out then how to iterate trough them, even the ones that aren't loaded until the page is scrolled down ?

Comment: You mean that page should get data from some `XHR` to render more content? I'd suggest you to try in loop `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body').send_keys(Keys.END)` to scroll page down and trigger new `XHR`, but it could be not that simple